# How does exactly fitting with SGD in Keas works?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm a newbie in a Neural Networks. I'm doing my university NN project in Keras. I assembled and trained the one-layer sequential model using SGD optimizer:

```
[...]
nn_model = Sequential()
nn_model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='tanh'))
nn_model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.25)
nn_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = nn_model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2000, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
[...]
```

I've tried various learning rate, momentum, neurons and get satisfying accuracy and error results. But, I have to know how keras works. So could you please explain me how exactly fitting in keras works, because I can't find it in Keras documentation?

- How does Keras update weights? Does it use a backpropagation algorithm? (I'm 95% sure.)
- How SGD algorithm is implemented in Keras? Is it similar to [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)?
- How Keras exactly calculate a gradient?

Thank you kindly for any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to break it down and I'll cover only Keras specific bits:

1. *How does Keras update weights?* Using an `Optimiser` which is a base class for different optimisers. Each optimiser calculates the new weights, under a function [get_updates](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5fcd832b5c5025b164c99f0bd46cb94d707b93d3/keras/optimizers.py#L74) which returns a list of functions when run applies the updates.
2. *Back-propagation?* Yes, but Keras doesn't implement it directly, it leaves it for the backend tensor libraries to perform automatic differentiation. For example [K.gradients](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/794f814343b655e01de73578d71e8b8a53523687/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2693) calls `tf.gradients` in the Tensorflow backend.
3. *SGD algorithm?* It is implemented as expected on Wikipedia in the [SGD](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5fcd832b5c5025b164c99f0bd46cb94d707b93d3/keras/optimizers.py#L146L9) class with the basic extensions such as momentum. You can follow the code easily and how it calculates the updates.
4. *How gradient is calculated?* Using back-propagation.

Comment: Thank you for explainations :) Now I know from should I learn to pass my AI